# decryption failed or bad record mac : CurlException : 56

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app, i'm getting current user's friends with an Fql query but receive this error :

```
[result:protected] => Array
    (
        [error_code] => 56
        [error] => Array
            (
                [message] => SSL read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0
                [type] => CurlException
            )

    )
```

Also i test application with a Test User that i created, and i see a list of friends but with my user profile i've got this error.. why ?

Hosting : Altervista

Facebook SDK for PHP v.3